# Blender collada export/import

Tags: blender, collada

It seems that there is problem with blender and "Collada" in Ubuntu, no "Collada" export or import option, any solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download 
and follow the instructions

https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter

Answer (score 0):

Blender uses the [opencollada library](http://www.opencollada.org/) to provide support for collada import and export. This library must be installed on your system and blender built using it to have the import/export collada options.

The official *nix builds are not built with collada support enabled, either you need to use a non-official build of blender, build your own version, or use a third-party addon that provides collada support. As you mentioned in your own answer, the [godot project](https://godotengine.org) has a [python only collada addon](https://github.com/godotengine/collada-exporter) that may be used for collada exporting.